# Insert multiple rows into a table from two different tables in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert multiple rows into my  table using select but I'm getting not enough values error.

My query:

```
Insert into c(x, y) select * from a union all select * from d;
```

> table a and b contains 2 records each and table c has one record.

Comment: The query looks correct. What is the error you get? Please **[edit]** your question and add the **exact** error message

Answer (score 1):

try like below by specifying both column names

```
Insert into c(x, y) 
select col1,col2 from a
 union all 
select col1,col2 from d
```

for `union all` both tables have the same number of colums and their data type also need to be same

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually i was editing but before that i did the post

Answer (score 1):

List the columns explicitly:

```
Insert into c (x, y)
    select col1, col2
    from a
    union all
    select col1, col2
    from d;
```

If one of tables has only one column, then use a placeholder for the value:

```
Insert into c (x, y)
    select col1, col2
    from a
    union all
    select col1, NULL
    from d;
```